# Parity scheduled transaction stuck at submitting

Tags: transactions, blockchain, parity, tokens

I scheduled a transaction for the BAT token after block 3798640. It remained pending before the block for hours, then submitted about an hour ago, [see Tx local viewer screenshot](https://screencast.com/t/1yPt5CxWdP). Anyone know if this transaction will go through? Alternatively, is there a way to make sure it is cancelled?

Comment: The blockchain is full due to the BAT token sale for 5-6 hours now. With a "low" gas price of only 23 GWei you will probably wait several hours till it gets mined.